# Vocational training to be a thief?

Tags: story-identification

I have a very vague memory of this book... a boy is allowed to choose any sort of training, and decides to train to be a thief. At some point he either orders or perhaps steals a screwdriver. More likely he ordered the screwdriver to use it to steal something else, or gain access.

Though my memory of this story is extremely unclear I always had the impression it was as science fiction story. I had the impression that the boy may have time traveled into the future; and the 'vocational training' I am thinking of was, I think, at least partly run by computer. At least the element where he orders the screwdriver was some kind of automated system.

I would have read this most likely in the mid-1980s. I believe it was a purely textual book, possibly a novel; not a comic book or illustrated story I don't think.

I wish I could remember more! Any ideas?

Comment: Terse indeed, so just in case, [here are the guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) for story-ID, if that triggers anything more :) Surely you can at least give us s time of reading/publishing?

Comment: What about this story is science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: @Jenayah thank you for the guidelines, I've added some information based on that.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod I've updated the question to clarify that as best as I can recall. Thanks